# GWT onResize on RentAvailabilityGraphPresenter extends AppPresenter

Tags: java, gwt

I tried the following approaches:

1. Using a Window.addResizeHandler:

```
protected void onBind() {

  Window.addResizeHandler(event -> {
            int debugME=2;
   });
}
```

2 . or Implementing ProvidesResize and RequiresResize interfaces:

```
@Override
public void onResize() {
      int a = 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, none of the above methods seem to trigger the resize event.

If anyone has encountered similar issues and found a solution, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You "tried the following approaches" to solve what? Please elaborate on your scenario.

Comment: Sorry me :( , the first solution worked fine. The issue was on my side.